# I used fs.readFile() twice on the same file but it says its diffrent?

Tags: node.js

I used fs.readFile() to see if a file has been changed, but it always says it has even if I have done nothing to the file.

```
const config = {
    "interval": 100,
    "file": "./test.txt"
}
const fs = require("fs")
let data
fs.readFile(config.file, (err, d) => {
    if (err) throw err
    data = d
})
setInterval(check, config.interval)
function check() {
    let newdata
    fs.readFile(config.file, (err, d) => {
        if (err) throw err
        newdata = d
    })
    if (data != newdata) {
        fs.readFile(config.file, (err, d) => {
            if (err) throw err
            data = d
        })
        console.log("Changed")
    }
}
```

Comment: The `fs.readFile` is asynchronous which means when you compare data and newdata you are comparing `data` and `undefined` since `newdata` has not yet been assigned anything to it. So either use `fs.readFileSync` or do the comparison within the `fs.readFile` callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if (data != newdata)` comparison is occurring BEFORE you've assigned anything to `newdata` because `fs.readFile()` is asynchronous and non-blocking so it's callback gets called sometime later.  If you did a simple `console.log()` on the two values, you would see that `newdata` is still `undefined`.

You can fix it by moving the comparison INSIDE the `fs.readFile()` callback.

```
function check() {
    fs.readFile(config.file, (err, newdata) => {
        if (!err && data !== newdata) {
            console.log("Changed")
            // do whatever you wanted to do here
        }
    });
}
```